# GRUB menu on boot

Tags: grub2

GRUB menu showing up at the beginning of boot:
Ubuntu 18.10 no dual-boot
Dell XPS 13 9370
How to fix this

My GRUB Conf:

GRUB_DEFAULT="0"
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="hidden"
GRUB_TIMEOUT="0"
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""